# MySQL - NULL value check and Dynamic SQL inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic, null

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS HaveSomeFun;
CREATE PROCEDURE HaveSomeFun(user_id CHAR(50),house_id CHAR(50),room_id CHAR(50),fun_text TEXT,video_url CHAR(100))
BEGIN
 DECLARE query_full TEXT;
 SET @fields_part = 'INSERT INTO fun(FunKey,UserKey,FunBody,LastModified';
 SET @values_part = CONCAT(') VALUES( NewBinKey(), KeyToBin(\"', user_id, '\"), \"', fun_text, '\", NOW() ');
 IF (house_id) THEN
  SET @fields_part = CONCAT(@fields_part, ', HouseKey');
  SET @values_part = CONCAT(@values_part, ', KeyToBin(\'', house_id, '\')');
 END IF;
 IF (room_id) THEN
  SET @fields_part = CONCAT(@fields_part, ', RoomKey');
  SET @values_part = CONCAT(@values_part, ', KeyToBin(\'', room_id, '\')');
 END IF;
 IF (video_url IS NOT NULL) THEN
  SET @fields_part = CONCAT(@fields_part, ', VideoURL');
  SET @values_part = CONCAT(@values_part, ', "', video_url, '"');
 END IF;
 SET query_full  = CONCAT(@fields_part, @values_part, ' );');
 SET @query_full = query_full;
 PREPARE STMT FROM @query_full;
 EXECUTE STMT;
 SELECT query_full;
END;
```

And

```
CALL HaveSomeFun('29B455DE-A9BC-102D-9C16-00163EEDFCFC', '', 'F82C47A8-64DE-11DF-9D7E-0026B9481364', 'Jokes apart', '');
```

will construct the below string in the variable query_full

```
INSERT INTO fun(FunKey,UserKey,FunBody,LastModified, VideoURL) VALUES( NewBinKey(), KeyToBin("29B455DE-A9BC-102D-9C16-00163EEDFCFC"), "Jokes apart", NOW() , "" );
```

But I need to get

```
INSERT INTO fun(FunKey,UserKey,FunBody,LastModified, RoomKey, VideoURL) VALUES( NewBinKey(), KeyToBin("29B455DE-A9BC-102D-9C16-00163EEDFCFC"), "Jokes apart", NOW() , KeyToBin('F82C47A8-64DE-11DF-9D7E-0026B9481364'), "" );
```

Something is missing in the check `IF (room_id) THEN`. But I cannot impose `IF (room_id IS NOT NULL) THEN` since it will create KeyToBin('') and RoomKey is foreign key , KeyToBin('') will produce an invalid RoomKey.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the issue, it should be like

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS HaveSomeFun;
CREATE PROCEDURE HaveSomeFun(user_id CHAR(50),house_id CHAR(50),room_id CHAR(50),fun_text TEXT,video_url CHAR(100))
BEGIN
 DECLARE query_full TEXT;
 SET @fields_part = 'INSERT INTO fun(FunKey,UserKey,FunBody,LastModified';
 SET @values_part = CONCAT(') VALUES( NewBinKey(), KeyToBin(\"', user_id, '\"), \"', fun_text, '\", NOW() ');
 IF (house_id != '') THEN
  SET @fields_part = CONCAT(@fields_part, ', HouseKey');
  SET @values_part = CONCAT(@values_part, ', KeyToBin(\'', house_id, '\')');
 END IF;
 IF (room_id != '') THEN
  SET @fields_part = CONCAT(@fields_part, ', RoomKey');
  SET @values_part = CONCAT(@values_part, ', KeyToBin(\'', room_id, '\')');
 END IF;
 IF (video_url IS NOT NULL) THEN
  SET @fields_part = CONCAT(@fields_part, ', VideoURL');
  SET @values_part = CONCAT(@values_part, ', "', video_url, '"');
 END IF;
 SET query_full  = CONCAT(@fields_part, @values_part, ' );');
 SET @query_full = query_full;
 PREPARE STMT FROM @query_full;
 EXECUTE STMT;
 SELECT query_full;
END;
```